# need to create a list from a text file

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I need to return a list of pairs (datetime.date(x,y,z), number of times it appears) in a text file with 1,000 entries. The function `def eventfreq(year, month):`takes the year and month of the previously mentioned datetime.date as parameters. So far, I have defined year and month

```
def eventfreq(year, month):
    F=fieldict('DOT1000.txt')
    for line in F:
        year=F[1].year
        month=F[1].month
```

fieldict is a function that takes returns a tuple of (Manufacturer, datetime.date(), year, crash, injury) for each entry in the file. I only need it to extract the datetime from each entry. I am very new to python, i've been up all night working on several of these functions.

EDIT: Sample Data:

503 958504 GENERAL MOTORS CORP. CHEVROLET LUMINA 1990 19920606 N 0 0 SERVICE BRAKES, HYDRAULIC:FOUNDATION COMPONENTS:DISC:CALIPER DRACUT MA 2G1WN14T9L9 19950110 19950110 PROBLEM WITH CALIPERS FREEZING UP MANUFACTURER OFFERS NO ASSISTANCE. TT EVOQ

This is 1 entry of 1,000. I need advice on how to build my list of pairs [(datetime.date(), #of occurences in the file)]. Year and month are the parameters for the function

EDIT: test cases:

```
>>> evlist = eventfreq(1995,1)
>>> len(evlist)
17
>>> evlist[0]
(datetime.date(1995, 1, 1), 5)
>>> evlist[14]
(datetime.date(1995, 1, 15), 1)
```

EDIT: Another Sample Entry:

1332    477660  HONDA (AMERICAN HONDA MOTOR CO.)    ACURA   INTEGRA 1994        **19940601**    N   0   0   VISIBILITY:WINDSHIELD   TUSTIN          CA  JH4DC4359RS 19950112    19941112        1   WINDOW PROBLEMS.  *AK   VOQ

In bold is the date. I already have it in datetime.date format(imported datetime module) and it is in the same place in every entry. Need a list that contains pairs (datetime.date(year,month,day) , # of times the same **year** and **month** appear in the file)

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data. And please: what is your question?

Comment: Since you ask about '#of occurences in the file' it would be *very* helpful if you provide more than one sample row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `fielddict()` returns a list of tuples, like this:

```
[('m1', datetime.date(1995, 1, 1), 'y1', 'c1', 'i1'),
('m2', datetime.date(1995, 1, 15), 'y2', 'c2', 'i2'),
('m3', datetime.date(1995, 1, 1), 'y3', 'c3', 'i3')]
```

Your function `eventfreq()` could be:

```
def eventfreq(year, month):
    F=fieldict('DOT1000.txt')
    #Get a list of datetimes matching year and month
    lst = [i[1] for i in F if((i[1].year == year) & (i[1].month == month))]
    #return a list of tuples (datetime, count)
    return [(i, lst.count(i)) for i in set(lst)]
```

Now your testcases should work as you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know how to extract the integer dates from your file into a list:

```
import datetime
dates = [19940903, 19940907, 19940801, 19950701, 19950702]
formated_dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(str(i), '%Y%m%d') for i in dates]
year_month_pairs = [(i.year, i.month) for i in formated_dates]
unique = set(year_month_pairs)
counts = [(i, year_month_pairs.count(i)) for i in unique]
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I tried to get the date from the 1st word in the line matching format `%Y%m%d` (see [this link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime.date#strftime-strptime-behavior) for more details), here is what it gives:

```
>>> dict_dates = {}
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> for line in open(r'D:\DATA\FP12210\My Documents\Temp\Python\Dates.txt'):
    for word in line.split():
        try:
            # Try to convert
            date = datetime.strptime(word, '%Y%m%d')
            # Conversion succeeded
            dict_dates[date] = dict_dates.get(date, 0) + 1
            break
        except:
            pass


>>> dict_dates
{datetime.datetime(1994, 6, 1, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(1992, 6, 6, 0, 0): 1}
>>>
```

I created a file with the 2 lines you provided.